# Cannot remove shapes in Java using mouseEvents

Tags: java, object, methods, mouseevent, shapes

I am trying to make an original game in Eclipse and I am having some trouble writing code that will remove GObjects and change the properties of others, using the mouseClicked method.

The problem seems to be that the private instant variables are not being recognised in the mousePressed method.

Can someone please advise on what I'm getting wrong here? I have spent a whole day on this and some help will be greatly appreciated.

Kind regards,

Mehul

```
*/*
 * File: Linesv1.java
 * 07/08/2012
 * 
 */
import acm.graphics.*;
import acm.program.*;
import acm.util.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.event.MenuEvent;
public class Linesv1 extends GraphicsProgram {


    /** Width and height of application window in pixels */
    public static final int BACKGROUND_WIDTH = 400;
    public static final int BACKGROUND_HEIGHT = 600;
    /** Dimensions of game board (usually the same) */
    private static final int WIDTH = BACKGROUND_WIDTH;
    private static final int HEIGHT = BACKGROUND_HEIGHT;

    /** Dimensions of triangle*/
    private static final int LENGTH_OF_TRIANGLE_SIDE = 100;

    /** Dimensions of arc height*/
    private static final int ARC_HEIGHT = 100;

    /** Dimensions of radius of switches*/
    private static final int SWITCH_RADII = 5;


    // private instant variables

    private GObject switchA;

    private GOval switchB;

    private GObject triangle;


    private GObject bottomArc;


public void run() {
        addMouseListeners();
        setUpGame();
        }

public void setUpGame(){

    //add central triangle
    GPolygon triangle = new GPolygon (WIDTH/2,HEIGHT/2);
    triangle.addVertex(0,-LENGTH_OF_TRIANGLE_SIDE*2/3);
    triangle.addVertex(LENGTH_OF_TRIANGLE_SIDE/2,+LENGTH_OF_TRIANGLE_SIDE*1/3);
    triangle.addVertex(-LENGTH_OF_TRIANGLE_SIDE/2,+LENGTH_OF_TRIANGLE_SIDE*1/3);
    triangle.setFilled(true);
    triangle.setFillColor(Color.green);
    add(triangle);

    //add topArc
    GArc bottomArc = new  GArc (WIDTH/2-LENGTH_OF_TRIANGLE_SIDE/2, HEIGHT/2+LENGTH_OF_TRIANGLE_SIDE*1/3-ARC_HEIGHT/2, ARC_HEIGHT,ARC_HEIGHT,0,-180);
    bottomArc.setFilled(true);
    bottomArc.setFillColor(Color.green);
    add(bottomArc);

    //add switches to the bottom of the triangle
    GOval switchA = new GOval (WIDTH/2-LENGTH_OF_TRIANGLE_SIDE/2-SWITCH_RADII, HEIGHT/2+LENGTH_OF_TRIANGLE_SIDE*1/3-SWITCH_RADII,SWITCH_RADII*2,SWITCH_RADII*2);
    switchA.setFilled(true);
    switchA.setFillColor(Color.black);
    add(switchA);

    //add switches to the bottom of the triangle
    GOval switchB = new GOval (WIDTH/2+LENGTH_OF_TRIANGLE_SIDE/2-SWITCH_RADII, HEIGHT/2+LENGTH_OF_TRIANGLE_SIDE*1/3-SWITCH_RADII,SWITCH_RADII*2,SWITCH_RADII*2);
    switchB.setFilled(true);
    switchB.setFillColor(Color.black);
    add(switchB);
    }
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    findObject(e.getX(),e.getY());
    GObject check = findObject(e.getX(),e.getY());
    if (check!=null){
        remove(triangle);
        switchA.setColor(Color.cyan);
    }
}
private GObject findObject(int a, int b){

    if(getElementAt(a,b) != null) {
        return getElementAt(a,b);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
}*
```

Comment: cannot be recognized? all of them? But you did not create the objects. you just declared types. am i right?

Comment: Which are the variables that cannot be recognized?

Comment: From Jeff's answer it seems as if the instance variables I declared at the top of the body are not the GObjects that I added in the setUpGame(); method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The triangle you are trying to remove is not the one you added.  You created a local GPolygon called triangle in setupGame() and added that, not the private member.

```
 private GObject triangle; // this is uninitialized

 public void setUpGame(){

   GPolygon triangle = new GPolygon (WIDTH/2,HEIGHT/2);  // this is hiding your member variable

   // THIS IS LOCAL COPY, NOT MEMBER VARIABLE
   add(triangle);
```

And then later you try to remove the uninitialized member variable, so nothing happens.  You probably don't want a separate local copy of triangle.  You probably want

```
  public void setUpGame() {
    triangle = new GPolygon (WIDTH/2, HEIGHT/2);
    // ...
    add(triangle); // Now, you are adding the member
  }
```

Comment: It worked like a charm. Thanks for taking the time to help me out Jeff. I appreciate it a lot.